# searching in VBA with a certian number format

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a sub that uses a chunk of a code as a search term and finds it in a different row. I am trying to search for a four digit code such as `0032` but no matter what I try, it searches for `32` and ends up finding sections such as `1132`, `1321`, and `3211`,which I don't want. This is what I have right now to address the problem.

```
    For i = 1 To frng.Count
crng(i, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(mfrng, cfrng(i, 1).Value)
Next i
'puts the number of times it appears next to the filtered version of it

'to find the row number
'use numbers from cfrng to search in mcode range and find rownumbers. Then add one to the rownumber and use it to copy and paste the other columns. Organize by lcode + 40000
Dim wrrow As Long
Dim wdrow As Long
Dim flist As Range
    rangevalue = ("R2:R" & flastrow)
    Set flist = Range(rangevalue)
Dim nlist As Range
    rangevalue = ("S2:S" & flastrow)
    Set nlist = Range(rangevalue)
Dim Search As Variant
Dim j As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim found As Object

For j = 1 To flist.Count
    Search = flist(j, 1)
    n = nlist(j, 1)
    Set found = mfrng.Find(What:=Search, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, searchformat:=True)
        Dim s As Integer
        For s = 1 To n
        If s = 1 Then GoTo First Else GoTo Second

First:
        wrrow = found.Row
        wdrow = (wrrow + 1)
         wd.Activate
            Dim high As Range
            rangevalue = ("V" & wdrow & ", AA" & wdrow & ", D" & wdrow & ", E" & wdrow & ", L" & wdrow & ", M" & wdrow & ", U" & wdrow)
            Set high = Range(rangevalue)
        high.Select
        Selection.Copy
        wr.Activate
        Dim r As Integer
        Dim v As Integer
            r = wr.Cells(wr.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            v = (r + 1)
        wr.Range("B" & v).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        wr.Range("A" & v).Value = j
        GoTo Third

Second:
        Set found = mfrng.FindNext(found)
        wrrow = found.Row
        wdrow = (wrrow + 1)
            wd.Activate
            rangevalue = ("V" & wdrow & ",AA" & wdrow & ",D" & wdrow & ",E" & wdrow & ",L" & wdrow & ",M" & wdrow & ",U" & wdrow)
            Set high = Range(rangevalue)
        high.Select
        Selection.Copy
            r = wr.Cells(wr.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            v = (r + 1)
        wr.Activate
        Range("B" & v).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        wr.Range("A" & v).Value = j

Third:
        Next s
Next j
```

The value in flist is displayed as `0032` but when I try and use the search it represents `32`, not `0032`.  When I try the number format it returns an object required error.

I have set the search to a variant.

Some examples of what I am comparing the search to are `0032`, which is the one I want, but also `2132`, `3225`, etc. I only want it to find the rows with `0032`.

I have a list of search terms which is what the j variable changes. I also have a number of the times a certain variable appears which is what the nlist is.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to find that string. Show more of your code, along with samples of your data and expected output. Might be helpful if you read [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you are searching for `0032` then you are effectively searching for text and not a number. If the range being searched is also text then everything is fine and you merely need to ensure that `Dim Search as String`. If the range consists of numbers then you won't find a match and you should `Dim Search as Long` and then search for the number `32` instead (and everything will be fine again no matter the formatting of the numbers in the search range. So, just share with us how you declared `Search` and what kind of values (examples) are being searched.

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` at the top of your code module.  This requires declaration of all variables, and will help pick up typos, undeclared variables (eg: `Search` is not declared in the code you posted), and other issues.  Especially since `.numberformat` is a property of a `Range` object, I suspect `Search` is not a `Range`; hence your `object required` error.  Also, include **ALL** of the optional arguments in your `.Find` statement.  And if you need more help, then answer the question posed by both me and @Ralph regarding providing samples of your data and expected output.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I have updated the code. But it still doesn't only look for the `0032`. Just the `32`. I would appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: I would expect that since you are using the argument `lookat:=xlpart`.

Comment: this is really bad code `If s = 1 Then GoTo First Else GoTo Second` ... there is absolutely no reason why you should use a `goto` statement ..... please learn about correct VBA form of `if ... then ... else`

Comment: As stated in my comment above: if you want to search for text then you should declare your variable as such `Dim Search as String` and not as a variant. Furthermore @RonRosenfeld gave you the perfect hint: if you are comparing partial cell values with `xlPart` then you'll also get partial matches. But if you compare `0032` only with cells which contain exactly this (including the leading zeros) in `xlWhole` then you'll get just that. Nothing else. Apart from that here are a few more hints: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uhtps9pvi5xkja1/CodeChanges.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From everyone's advice I was able to figure it out.

This is what my final code looks like.

```
Dim wrrow As Long
Dim wdrow As Long
Dim flist As Range
    rangevalue = ("R2:R" & flastrow)
    Set flist = Range(rangevalue)
Dim nlist As Range
    rangevalue = ("S2:S" & flastrow)
    Set nlist = Range(rangevalue)
Dim Search As String
Dim codenum As Integer
Dim seriesnum As Integer
Dim found As Range
Dim current As Integer
Dim high As Range
Dim blastcell As Integer
Dim bemptycell As Integer
Dim findrng As Range
    rangevalue = ("O1:O" & rlastrow)
    Set findrng = Range(rangevalue)

For codenum = 1 To flist.Count
    Search = flist(codenum, 1)
    seriesnum = nlist(codenum, 1)

        For current = 1 To seriesnum

            If current = 1 Then
                Set found = findrng.Find(What:=Search, LookAt:=xlWhole, searchformat:=True)
                wrrow = found.Row
                wdrow = (wrrow + 1)
                wd.Activate
                rangevalue = ("V" & wdrow & ", AA" & wdrow & ", D" & wdrow & ", E" & wdrow & ", L" & wdrow & ", M" & wdrow & ", U" & wdrow)
                Set high = Range(rangevalue)
                high.Select
                Selection.Copy
                wr.Activate
                blastcell = wr.Cells(wr.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                bemptycell = (blastcell + 1)
                wr.Range("B" & bemptycell).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                wr.Range("A" & bemptycell).Value = codenum
                GoTo Next_item
            End If
                Set found = mfrng.FindNext(found)
                wrrow = found.Row
                wdrow = (wrrow + 1)
                wd.Activate
                rangevalue = ("V" & wdrow & ",AA" & wdrow & ",D" & wdrow & ",E" & wdrow & ",L" & wdrow & ",M" & wdrow & ",U" & wdrow)
                Set high = Range(rangevalue)
                high.Select
                Selection.Copy
                wr.Activate
                blastcell = wr.Cells(wr.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                bemptycell = (blastcell + 1)
                wr.Range("B" & bemptycell).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                wr.Range("A" & bemptycell).Value = codenum
Next_item:
    Next current
    Next codenum
```

It now does exactly what I wanted it to and only returns the cells with a code exactly matching the codenum.